# How to limit click event for example 5 times per day, and after that disable it and enable click only on next day?

Tags: java, android

I have Spinning wheel for prizes. I want to set a limit to the number of clicks per day. For example, 5 clicks per day. I just want to make user clicks only 5 times per day and disable click-event for that day afterwards. The clicks would be re-enabled the next day.

```
 ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    final SharedPreferences coins = getSharedPreferences("Rewards", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final LuckyWheelView luckyWheelView = (LuckyWheelView) findViewById(R.id.luckyWheel);
    findViewById(R.id.play).setEnabled(true);
    findViewById(R.id.play).setAlpha(1f);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    weekday = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    todayString = year + "" + month + "" + day;
    final SharedPreferences spinChecks = getSharedPreferences("SPINCHECK",0);
    final boolean currentDay = spinChecks.getBoolean(todayString, false);
```

Comment: A dumb way would be to store the spins they have made and the last spin time in a database, and check it everytime they spin.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by SharedPrefs.

```
private void TestDate(String todayString) {
        final SharedPreferences spinChecks = getSharedPreferences("SPINCHECK",0);
        if(spinChecks.getString("date","").equals(todayString)){
            if(spinChecks.getInt("count",0)<5){
                spinChecks.edit().putInt("count",spinChecks.getInt("count",0)+1).apply();
                System.out.println("Allow : date "+todayString+" count "+spinChecks.getInt("count",0));
            }else{
                System.out.println("Do not Allow : date "+todayString+" count "+spinChecks.getInt("count",0));
            }

        }else{
            spinChecks.edit().putString("date",todayString).apply();
            spinChecks.edit().putInt("count",1).apply();
            System.out.println("Allow : date "+todayString+" count "+spinChecks.getInt("count",0));
        }
    }
```

the above is just a rough idea how to do it.

another thing you can do is store all the history in the Sqlite and query the database for the count of records of that particular day.
Of course it will take some space but you can show history to user by storing it to sqlite.
Above answers are good but has a drawback like if user clean / remove data he would be able to do spins again. for that i would suggest you to store the daily count in remote database and query it evertime user clicks on spin button